# How to change an array to boolean values making the array output True/False

Tags: python

Make a new array where the elements are all Boolean values, representing whether or not the corresponding values in the solved board are odd.  (That is to say, if a value is odd, the new array should have True in its corresponding location.)

Currently my code just outputs whether the values are true or false, but are not in the 9x9 array I need it to be in.

```
Array
solvedBoard = np.array([
                    [5, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 2],
                    [6, 7, 2, 1, 9, 5, 3, 4, 8],
                    [1, 9, 8, 3, 4, 2, 5, 6, 7],
                    [8, 5, 9, 7, 6, 1, 4, 2, 3],
                    [4, 2, 6, 8, 5, 3, 7, 9, 1],
                    [7, 1, 3, 9, 2, 4, 8, 5, 6],
                    [9, 6, 1, 5, 3, 7, 2, 8, 4],
                    [2, 8, 7, 4, 1, 9, 6, 3, 5],
                    [3, 4, 5, 2, 8, 6, 1, 7, 9]])


INPUT:
for item in np.nditer(solvedBoard1):
    if item%2 ==0:
    print("False")
else:
    print("True")

OUTPUT:
True
True
False
False
True
False
True etc...
```

Comment: `solvedBoard % 2`

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Have you tried anything, done any research?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a simple comparison `answer = solvedBoard % 2 == 0`

Comment: Thanks a ton, also do you know how I would flip the Boolean value so instead of showing an odd number as false, it would show as true?

Comment: No problem! Just change the condition to `solvedBoard %2 == 1`